# Check if an argument is a double

Tags: c

Iḿ developing a program and I need to check if one of the char arrays passed by the argv are numbers, the problem comes when I have parameters like 2_two or 2-2 , what I've tryed doesn't works cause catch the number 2 and keeps the program running when it should exit.
I have tryed with atrof(), sprintf(), but didn work.

```
double from;
double to;
double jump;
switch (argc){
    case 2: to = atof(argv [1]); from =10; jump =1; break;
    case 3: to = atof(argv [1]); from = atof(argv[2]); jump = 1; break;
    case 4: to = atof(argv [1]); from = atof(argv[2]); jump =atof(argv [3]); break;
    default: from=1; to = 10; jump =1;
}
if (from == 0.0){
    char message []= "The parameter \"from\" is not a valid number";
    Error(EX_USAGE,message);
}else if (to==0.0){
    char message []= "The parameter \"to\" is not a valid number";
    Error(EX_USAGE,message);
}else if (jump==0.0){
    char message []= "The parameter \"jump\" is not a valid number";
    Error(EX_USAGE,message);
}
```

The method Error is an auxiliar that exit the program with the code error and the message

So what I need is the program exit when I get a parameter that is not just number.

Comment: I have parameters like 2_two or 2-2  ? Is it double? Why cant you pass properly?

Comment: The problem is the methods I've tryed capture the value 2 and keeps the program running when it should stop, what I need is to detect when some of the arguments have something that is not just a number.

Comment: Use `strtod()` — but you'll probably want to wrap it in a function that does the checking. The `strtoX()` functions are powerful and useful, but also hard to use correctly. It also depends on how fussy you want to be. If the string is `"2pies"`, is that a valid representation of `2`?  The `strtoX()` functions will say yes, it's a valid number, and the first non-numeric character was the `p`; it is then up to you to decide whether the `pies` are a problem. The functions would report that `"pies * 2"` is not a number, but you have to know how they do that; they return 0. That's why you wrap 'em.

Comment: '2pies' is not a valid representation, and in this case it should exit the program too, to be more clear, any string that have something that isn't a number (symbols like + * / - inclueded) should stop the program too.

Comment: How do you want to handle leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: So, you don't want `+3.0` or `-4.2` to be allowed?  What about `3.14E+14` and related notations?  Hexadecimal floating point?  And, as Keith mentioned, what about leading and trailing white space.  Disallowing leading signs is fiddly but can be done with a custom parsing function (wrapper to `strtod()` that processes the data).  Disallowing exponent notation (`3.14E-46`) is also doable, as is disallowing hex.

Comment: Basically, you'd arrange to skip (or generate errors on) white space; generate an error on a sign; track the start of the digits (or decimal point, unless you ban `.25` as invalid), skip over digits and up to one decimal point; check whether there's only white space following (no exponents); and if it all meets your criteria, pass the start of the digits to `strtod()` to do the delicate work of converting the number.  You'd carefully check the return value from `strtod()`.  You can tweak the rules for what you accept before you call `strtod()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strtod` (include `<stdlib.h>`)

```
double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```

From the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)

> If endptr is not NULL, a pointer to the character after the last  character  used  in  the
>          conversion is stored in the location referenced by endptr.

Example of use

```
char *endptr;

double d = strtod(argv[1], &endptr);

int ok = endptr == argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]);
```

If `endptr` points to the trailing `\0` in `argv[1]`, that means the whole string was converted.

`ok` is `1` meaning the conversion was done up to the end of `argv[1]`.

```
if (ok) {
    // use `d`, the converted number
}
```

Comment: Rather than the ponderous `endptr == argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]);`, `*endptr == '\0'` will do.